# Placing <a> links on top of onclick div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a content tile that when clicked, activates another part of the screen.  On the tile, I have a couple links that, when clicked, go to new pages.  I made a non-javascript version that works fine.

No javascript:
https://jsfiddle.net/raazqqks/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="tile activeTile" id="response0">
    <div class="responseContainer">
        <div class="left">
            <h4 class="title">
                <a class="topLink" href="javascript:alert('Link clicked')">Title</a>
            </h4>
            <p>Foo bar</p>
            <p>Foo bar?</p>
            <p class="extra">
                <a class="topLink" href="javascript:alert('Link clicked')">Extra foo bar!</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bonus">
            <p>Bonus</p>
        </div>
        <a class="noJavaLink" id="0" href="javascript:alert('Tile clicked');"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.responseContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all linear .2s;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
}

.responseContainer p {
    margin: 0;
}

.tile {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 16px 48px 16px 32px;
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: all linear .2s;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.activeTile {
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
}

.activeTile > div {
    background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, .5);
}   

.left {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.title {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.title h4 {
    margin: 20px 0 20px;
}

.bonus {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.topLink {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.noJavaLink {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.active .noJavaLink {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

I want to add simple animations to it, so if javascript is available, this version loads.

Javascript:
https://jsfiddle.net/n4svaLut/

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setJavascriptTileAnimation(), false );

/*  Set onclick events for tile animation
|
*/
function setJavascriptTileAnimation() {
    var tiles = document.getElementsByClassName('tile')
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('noJavaLink');

    for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        var tile = tiles[i];
        var id = tile['id'];

        tile.onclick = function() {
            changeActiveTile(this.id);
            //return false;
        };

        links[i].removeAttribute('href');
    };
}

/*  Toggle active tile
|
*/
function changeActiveTile(id) {
    id_number = getIdNumber(id);

    active_tile = document.getElementsByClassName('tile activeTile')[0];

    active_tile.classList.remove('activeTile');

    setTimeout(function() {
        tile = document.getElementById(id);

        tile.classList.add('activeTile');
    }, 300);
}

function getIdNumber(id) {
    return id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
}
```

Notice how the  links only work on a double click.  Ive been playing around with this for two days and havent made any progress at all.  Any ideas?

SOLUTION: Remove 'return false' from the onclick setter.

Comment: You should not have `()` after the function name when you call `addEventListener`. That will call the function immediately, instead of calling it when the event occurs.

Comment: When I try your fiddle it works on a single click.

Comment: @Barmar the alert pops up with one click on the second link? Not for me in latest beta chrome

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about the animations.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the tip.  Still pretty new to javascript...

Comment: Yep, its the return false. Working: https://jsfiddle.net/n4svaLut/2/

Comment: That seems to do it.  Updated the fiddle.  Thanks!

Comment: Check your console for errors. If there's no active tile, `changeActiveTile` gets an error when it tries to do `active_tile.classList.remove('activeTile');` because `active_tile` is `null` and it has no `classList`.

Comment: I took error handling out of the fiddle to make it simpler.

Comment: I started testing this on mobile and am running into the same problem even with the new code. Any ideas?